# Composition of polymorphic functions

Tags: pattern-matching

Using pattern matching one can easily create polymorphic functions in Mathematica

```
f[{a_, b_}] := {a^2, b^2};
f[c_Integer] := c^4;
```

Now I want to create another function which is also polymorphic and calls the previous function, the simplest version of what I want to achieve is:

```
g[{a_, b_}] := f[f[{a, b}]];
g[c_Integer] := f[f[c]];
```

Note that the last two lines are "basically the same". What is the best way to avoid this redundancy? One possible solution I found is

```
Module[{a, b, c},
  Scan[Apply[(g[#1] := f[f[#2]]) &],{{{a_, b_}, {a, b}},{c_Integer, c}}]]
```

Other suggestions?
Note that the "catch all" `g[d_]:=f[f[d]]` is "not allowed", as it will give different results for example when g[3.5] is called.

Edit: In this case the following is also possible

```
g[x_]:=f[f[x]] /; IntegerQ[x] || (Length[x] == 2)
```

That might be a bit cumbersome for more complicated patterns however.

Edit 2: Also possible, same critique as above

```
g[x_Integer|x_List? (Length[#]==2&)]:=f[f[x]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the code

```
f[{a_, b_}] := {a^2, b^2};
f[c_Integer] := c^4;
g[x: _Integer | {a_, b_}] := f@f@x;
g /@ {2, {x, y}, 3.5} // InputForm
```

which returns the result

```
{65536, {x^4, y^4}, g[3.5]}
```

which is probably what you want.

Answer (score 6):

I think you can do:

```
g[x_] := With[{h = f[x]}, f[h] /; !MatchQ[h, _f]]
```

Then:

```
g /@ {2, {1, 2}, 3.5}
```

> {65536, {1, 16}, g[3.5]}

Answer (score 4):

Despite of what you say I would still recommend a "catch-all" that lets `g` inherit `f`'s polymorphism effortlessly. For this it is crucial that `g` is defined with a delayed assignment:

```
f[{a_, b_}] = {a^2, b^2};
f[c_Integer] = c^4;
f[___] = Indeterminate;

g[x___] := f[f[x]]
```

You can replace `Indeterminate` with whatever you prefer, like `$Failed` or some form of `Missing[]`.

Tests:

```
g /@ {2, {1, 2}, 3.5}
```

> {65536, {1, 16}, Indeterminate}